# How to use QueryInfo for pendingUrl in chrome.tabs.query?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

The chrome.tabs.query function in Chrome API has pendingUrl in addition to url.

However, how can the url filter be used if you have to consider this complication?

The Chrome API documentation has url in queryInfo, but not pendingUrl.

What if the address in the address bar changes from say chrome://settings to some https:// link?

Comment: There's no way to query it.

Comment: Thanks. So would you advice to use a reduce function to do it? Is it a good idea?

Comment: Use the standard JS approach e.g. filter() on the array returned by query().